# Cypress : set a variable in window.Cypress to be available in the tested application

Tags: cypress

With cy.window() you can access the tested application window object in a cypress test. We are looking for the other way around.

Without changing the url, is it possible to send the tested application a variable value in the window object so it's available when the application starts ?

Cypress Test :

```
setAppWindow("mySpecialFlag", true )
```

App Code Tested :

```
{
  if ( window.Cypress['mySpecialFlag] ) {
     // do something special
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're tryng to set a variable in `window.Cypress` to be available in the tested application, then the easiest would be to set it on Cypress global before the test starts.

```js
it('tests', () => {
  Cypress.mySpecialFlag = 'something';  // add to Cypress global

  cy.visit('/')     // Cypress global is appended to window
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Not entirely sure this gives you the right timing, but there is [Provide an onBeforeLoad callback function](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit#Provide-an-onBeforeLoad-callback-function)

```js
cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/#dashboard', {
  onBeforeLoad: (contentWindow) => {
    // contentWindow is the remote page's window object
    contentWindow.testing = true;
  },
})
```

I think `onBeforeLoad` occurs after the iframe window is set up but before the app is loaded to the browser, so any artifacts on the `contentWindow` object should be visible in the app `window` object.

For example, the app can see `window.Cypress` which is added during test build phase.